# Webclient not getting response uri

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, webclient

I found a strange behaviour in the `webclient` class. When i use the `UploadValues()` synchronous method i get the response uri normally, but when i use the async version `UploadValuesTaskAsync()` to the same url it returns the response uri as null. Why?

Example:

```
using (var client = new CustomWebClient())
{
    await Get(client);
    Get(client);
}

private async Task GetAsync(WebClient client)
{
      var resAsync = await client.UploadValuesTaskAsync("http://address.com", requestData); 
      //client.ResponseUri null here
}

private void Get(WebClient client)
{
    var res= client.UploadValues("http://address.com", requestData); 
     //client.ResponseUri **not** null here
}
```

In the `GetAsync` method the `client.ResponseUri` comes null, and not null for the `UploadValues`.

**EDIT:**

I discovered the WebClient is "customized":

so the class is:

```
 public class CustomWebClient : WebClient
 {
    public CookieContainer Cookies { get; private set; }
    public Uri ResponseUri { get; private set; }

    public CustomWebClient()
    {
        Cookies = new CookieContainer();
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request == null)
        {
            return base.GetWebRequest(address);
        }
        request.CookieContainer = Cookies;
        return request;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        var response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        ResponseUri = response.ResponseUri;
        return response;
    }
}
```

I checked that in the `synchronous` method it hits the `GetWebResponse` method before continous to the next line. But in the `asynchronous` version it not hit the `GetWebResponse` never.

Comment: You may want to change your GetAsync to void just to be consistent between the two examples

Comment: Its not a good practice to return void from a async method

Comment: Where exactly are you reading the ResponseUri from?

Comment: @Juan i edited the example in OP, im trying to read after the await request, from the client object.

Comment: I don't see a ResponseUri property anywhere. What version of the framework are you using?

Comment: @Juan you are right, i checked here and findout that the webclient is "customized". I put the CustomWebClient code in OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your customized class is only overriding the behavior for the synchronous `WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)` method.

You need to add an override for the async version:

```
 protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
 {
     var response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result);
     ResponseUri = response.ResponseUri;
     return response;
 }
```